# Scroll to end of UITextView when text contains returns

Tags: swift, scroll, uitextview, carriage-return, linefeed

I am using Swift and have a UITextView that I wish to always keep scrolling as I add new text and the length of the text is greater than what the textView can display.

The following works perfectly as long as my textview does not contain any new lines `"\n"`

```
let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.count - 1, 1)
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

However, as soon as I add a return, the range no longer is valid for the scroll.
I have checked out as many of the related posts as I can, but none seem to address this problem.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show more codes, I cannot find your problem.

Comment: This seems to work fine when I tried it with new lines. More info/code would help.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I discovered what the issue was.  if a UITextView is made unselectable, when you programatically add text to the view, the view will not scroll properly if there are returns in the text, whereas text without returns scrolled perfectly.
Here is a simple example.  Create a Viewcontroller with one button and a UITextView.
Wire it up and play with the two Bools.
You will find that if isSelectable = false and isReturnText = true then it will not scroll, however if isReturnText = false, it scrolls find.
If I set isSelectable = true then both scroll perfectly as expected.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var isSelectable:Bool = true
    var isReturnText:Bool = true


    let returnText = "These sentences are separated by returns.\n"
    let nonReturnText = "These sentences are separated by space. "

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.isSelectable = isSelectable

    }

    @IBAction func addNoReturnText(_ sender: Any) {
        textView.text += isReturnText ? returnText : nonReturnText
        let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.count - 1, 1)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
    }

}
```